# how to access a image tag from the external div with some id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a code in which there is a image tag which is inside the div's tag with some id i want to access the image tag property `src` & then change it but i want this generalized javascript code.

my code is:

```
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-16">
<div><img height="89" width="89" src="assets/rplay.png"></div>
</div>
```

& my javascript code is:

```
playButton=document.getElementById("p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-16");
```

now how i can access the `src` property of image tag by variable playButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** if you want to change the `src`, just set your new image url:

```js
var playButton=document.getElementById("p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-16");

playButton.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "http://i.imgur.com/RLKixQW.png"; // here
```

```html
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-16">
<div><img height="89" width="89" src="assets/rplay.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function and use a CSS selector.

```
var playButton = document.querySelectorAll("#p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-16 img")[0];
```

You can change src like this later:

```
playButton.src = "someothersrc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using getAttribute():
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp

Note, you have to remove all spaces between elements in the HTML.

```
var playButton=document.getElementById("p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-16").childNodes[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute("src");
```

Working Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/spanndemic/ghn2oner/

Comment: I don't think this will work. The attribute does not belong to the element with such `Id` - Ah! you fixed it... did you test it tho'? `childNodes[0]` may not be the node you want

Comment: still doesn't work.  it'd have to be `childNodes[0].childNodes[0]` since it is div -> div -> img, right?

Comment: @ps2goat you are right... with the caveat that this only works *if* the image is indeed the first child element of the first child element (not if there are other elements in between) ...

Comment: updated answer... you need two calls to childNodes, and to remove whitespace from the HTML

Comment: i want to change the src value so i have to use setAttribue or getAttribute?

Comment: correct, use setAttribute() to change the value... getAttribute() will retrieve the value